# Get internet address property of files in Temporary Internet Files folder

Tags: internet-explorer, vb6

I want to get `Internet address` for all files in `Temporary Internet Files` folder using VB6. How can i get those properties? In below image you can see those properties

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to use shell objects.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


'&h20 is temp internet files
Set Fldr=objShell.NameSpace(&h20)
'Set Fldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(0))
Set FldrItems=Fldr.Items
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


Set DeskFldr=objShell.Namespace(16)
FName=fso.buildpath(DeskFldr.self.path, "Folder Property List.txt")


Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(FName, 8, vbtrue)


'Getting the column headers for up to 51 columns
For x = 0 to 50
    t1 = t1 & Fldr.GetDetailsOf(vbnull, x) & " (Shell)" & vbtab
Next
ts.write FLDR.self.path & vbcrlf
ts.Write T1 & vbcrlf
T1=""

'Getting the details of each object
For Each FldrItem in FldrItems
    For x = 0 to 50
        t1 = t1 & Fldr.GetDetailsOf(FldrItem, x) & vbtab
    Next
    t1=t1 & vbcrlf
    ts.Write T1
    T1=""
Next

msgbox FName & "has a tab delimited list of all properties"
```

If you swap the SET FLDR= lines around then it will work for a folder dropped on it.

ShellSpecialFolderConstants Enumerated Type

---

CSIDL values provide a unique system-independent way to identify special folders used frequently by applications, but which may not have the same name or location on any given system. For example, the system folder may be "C:\Windows" on one system and "C:\Winnt" on another.

Syntax

```
typedef enum {
    ssfALTSTARTUP = 0x1d,
    ssfAPPDATA = 0x1a,
    ssfBITBUCKET = 0xa,
    ssfCOMMONALTSTARTUP = 0x1e,
    ssfCOMMONAPPDATA = 0x23,
    ssfCOMMONDESKTOPDIR = 0x19,
    ssfCOMMONFAVORITES = 0x1f,
    ssfCOMMONPROGRAMS = 0x17,
    ssfCOMMONSTARTMENU = 0x16,
    ssfCOMMONSTARTUP = 0x18,
    ssfCONTROLS = 0x3,
    ssfCOOKIES = 0x21,
    ssfDESKTOP = 0x0,
    ssfDESKTOPDIRECTORY = 0x10,
    ssfDRIVES = 0x11,
    ssfFAVORITES = 0x6,
    ssfFONTS = 0x14,
    ssfHISTORY = 0x22,
    ssfINTERNETCACHE = 0x20,
    ssfLOCALAPPDATA = 0x1c,
    ssfMYPICTURES = 0x27,
    ssfNETHOOD = 0x13,
    ssfNETWORK = 0x12,
    ssfPERSONAL = 0x5,
    ssfPRINTERS = 0x4,
    ssfPRINTHOOD = 0x1b,
    ssfPROFILE = 0x28,
    ssfPROGRAMFILES = 0x26,
    ssfPROGRAMS = 0x2,
    ssfRECENT = 0x8,
    ssfSENDTO = 0x9,
    ssfSTARTMENU = 0xb,
    ssfSTARTUP = 0x7,
    ssfSYSTEM = 0x25,
    ssfTEMPLATES = 0x15,
    ssfWINDOWS = 0x24
} ShellSpecialFolderConstants;
```

Constants

ssfALTSTARTUP
File system directory that corresponds to the user's nonlocalized Startup program group. (value = 29)

ssfAPPDATA
Version 4.71. File system directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data. (value = 26)

ssfBITBUCKET
Virtual folder containing the objects in the user's Recycle Bin. (value = 15)

ssfCOMMONALTSTARTUP
File system directory that corresponds to the nonlocalized Startup program group for all users. Valid only for Microsoft Windows NT systems. (value = 30)

ssfCOMMONAPPDATA
Version 5.0. Application data for all users. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data. (value = 35)

ssfCOMMONDESKTOPDIR
File system directory that contains files and folders that appear on the desktop for all users. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop. Valid only for Windows NT systems. (value = 25)

ssfCOMMONFAVORITES
File system directory that serves as a common repository for all users' favorite items. Valid only for Windows NT systems. (value = 31)

ssfCOMMONPROGRAMS
File system directory that contains the directories for the common program groups that appear on the Start menu for all users. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs. Valid only for Windows NT systems. (value = 23)

ssfCOMMONSTARTMENU
File system directory that contains the programs and folders that appear on the Start menu for all users. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu. Valid only for Windows NT systems. (value = 22)

ssfCOMMONSTARTUP
File system directory that contains the programs that appear in the Startup folder for all users. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup. Valid only for Windows NT systems. (value = 24)

ssfCONTROLS
Virtual folder containing icons for the Control Panel applications. (value = 3)

ssfCOOKIES
File system directory that serves as a common repository for Internet cookies. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\username\Cookies. (value = 33)

ssfDESKTOP
Microsoft Windows Desktop—virtual folder that is the root of the namespace. (value = 0)

ssfDESKTOPDIRECTORY
File system directory used to physically store the file objects that are displayed on the desktop. It is not to be confused with the desktop folder itself, which is a virtual folder. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\username\Desktop. (value = 16)

ssfDRIVES
My Computer—virtual folder containing everything on the local computer: storage devices, printers, and Control Panel. This folder may also contain mapped network drives. (value = 17)

ssfFAVORITES
File system directory that serves as a common repository for the user's favorite items. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\username\Favorites. (value = 6)

ssfFONTS
Virtual folder containing installed fonts. A typical path is C:\WINNT\Fonts. (value = 20)

ssfHISTORY
File system directory that serves as a common repository for Internet history items. (value = 34)

ssfINTERNETCACHE
File system directory that serves as a common repository for temporary Internet files. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\username\Temporary Internet Files. (value = 32)

ssfLOCALAPPDATA
Version 5.0. File system directory that serves as a data repository for local (non-roaming) applications. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data. (value = 28)

ssfMYPICTURES
My Pictures folder. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\My Pictures. (value = 39)

ssfNETHOOD
A file system folder containing the link objects that may exist in the My Network Places virtual folder. It is not the same as ssfNETWORK, which represents the network namespace root. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\username\NetHood. (value = 19)

ssfNETWORK
Network Neighborhood—virtual folder representing the root of the network namespace hierarchy. (value = 18)

ssfPERSONAL
File system directory that serves as a common repository for a user's documents. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents. (value = 5)

ssfPRINTERS
Virtual folder containing installed printers. (value = 4)

ssfPRINTHOOD
File system directory that contains the link objects that may exist in the Printers virtual folder. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\username\PrintHood. (value = 27)

ssfPROFILE
Version 5.0. User's profile folder. (value = 40)

ssfPROGRAMFILES
Version 5.0. Program Files folder. A typical path is C:\Program Files. (value = 38)

ssfPROGRAMS
File system directory that contains the user's program groups (which are also file system directories). A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\username\Start Menu\Programs. (value = 2)

ssfRECENT
File system directory that contains the user's most recently used documents. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\username\Recent. (value = 8)

ssfSENDTO
File system directory that contains Send To menu items. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\username\SendTo. (value = 9)

ssfSTARTMENU
File system directory containing Start menu items. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\username\Start Menu. (value = 11)

ssfSTARTUP
File system directory that corresponds to the user's Startup program group. The system starts these programs whenever any user logs onto Windows NT or starts Windows 95. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\username\Start Menu\Programs\Startup. (value = 7)

ssfSYSTEM
Version 5.0. System folder. A typical path is C:\WINNT\SYSTEM32. (value = 37)

ssfTEMPLATES
File system directory that serves as a common repository for document templates. (value = 21)

ssfWINDOWS
Version 5.0. Windows directory or SYSROOT. This corresponds to the %windir% or %SYSTEMROOT% environment variables. A typical path is C:\WINNT. (value = 36)

Remarks

The values in this enumeration are equivalent to the CSIDL values used in C++ applications. They supersede the use of environment variables for this purpose.

Note Where the a constant identifies a file system folder, a commonly used path on Windows 2000 systems is given as an example. However, there is no guarantee that this path will be used on any particular system, including Windows 2000 systems.